# Why does strcpy() force this for()-loop to iterate once more than without strcpy() and cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement my own Linux shell using C++. The following code is working fine:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // read the input command/arguments
    cout << "myshell >> ";
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);

    // if command is 'exit', exit myshell
    if (input == "exit")
    {
        cout << exit;
        exit(0);
    }

    // init stringstream
    stringstream in_stream(input);

    // create vector to store the parts of the command
    vector<string> parts;

    // string to store the parts during one iteration
    string part;

    // read all parts of the stringstream, separated by ' ' (space)
    while (getline(in_stream, part, ' '))
    {
        parts.push_back(part);
    }

    // create c-like array for passing it to the execvp() system call
    // execvp() needs nullptr as last element, thus: size() + 1
    const char* parts_arr[parts.size()+1];

    // store all elements of the parts vector in parts_arr as c-like strings
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++)
    {
        parts_arr[i] = parts[i].c_str();
    }

    // last element must be nullptr
    parts_arr[parts.size()] = nullptr;

    // init some variables
    int pid;
    int status;

    // fork and check the returned pid
    switch (pid = fork())
    {
    case -1:
        cerr << "fork() encountered an error." << endl;
        return 1;

    case 0: // child process
        if (execvp(parts_arr[0], const_cast<char *const *>(parts_arr)) == -1)
        {
            cerr << "Child: execvp() encountered an error." << endl;
            return 1;
        }

    default: // parent process
        if (waitpid(pid, &status,0) != pid)
        {
            cerr << "Parent: wait() encountered an error." << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        cerr << "Parent: child " << pid << " ended with status " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << endl; // least significant bits transport additional information
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./myshell
myshell >> ls -l
total 92
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 41576 Oct 17 13:24 a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 41824 Oct 18 22:19 myshell
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  2140 Oct 18 22:19 myshell.cpp
Parent: child 10538 ended with status 0
```

As one might think (me included): the const_cast in the execvp()-call just does not look right, so I was trying to clean-up and rewrite my code to eliminate the need for this cast.

Doing this, I encountered a problem modifying the creation of the c-like string array for the execvp() system call leading to a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. The following code snippets are the only lines of code I changed:

```
    (...)

    // create c-like array for passing it to the execvp() system call
    // execvp() needs nullptr as last element, thus: size() + 1
    char* parts_arr[parts.size()+1]; // <-- changed

    // store all elements of the parts vector in parts_arr as c-like strings
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++)
    {
        strcpy(parts_arr[i], parts[i].c_str()); // <-- changed
    }

    (...)

    case 0: // child process
        if (execvp(parts_arr[0], parts_arr) == -1) // <-- changed
        {
            cerr << "Child: execvp() encountered an error." << endl;
            return 1;
        }

    (...)
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./myshell
myshell >> ls -l
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

While debugging, I found that with the original code the for-loop iterates correctly, but using the new code it keeps iterating and causes the segmentation fault due to the faulty indexing.

Why does this happen? From my understanding, the for-loop should work equally for both codes, as the changes do not affect anything related to the iteration of the loop.

Also, I am open for any suggestion on how to improve the whole command/argument parsing, maybe completely eliminating the need for the conversion from the string-vector to the c-like string array.

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not standard C++, so what this does may depend on your compiler. Speaking about that, what do you use to compile this and what does it emit on a [mcve] when enabling warnings? That's the first thing I'd check. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> char* parts_arr[parts.size()+1]; // <-- changed
> ```

The size of an array variable must be compile time constant. `parts.size()+1` is not compile time constant. The program is ill-formed. That issue was already in the original version.

However, let's assume that you use non-standard language extensions that allow this. The array contains pointers. You've default initialised the array, and thus the pointers have indeterminate values.

> ```
> strcpy(parts_arr[i], parts[i].c_str());
> ```

`strcpy` requires that the fist argument is a **valid** pointer to sufficiently large amount of memory to fit the entire string. The pointers that you pass into `strcpy` are not valid pointers to sufficiently large amount of memory to fit the entire string. Not only does that violate the pre-conditions of the function, but also reading any indeterminate value of pointer type is never allowed. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> I was trying to clean-up and rewrite my code to eliminate the need for this cast.

Introducing `strcpy` is counter productive for "clean-up". It's a relic from C that you should avoid using it in C++.

There's a much easier way to avoid the cast. Changing the type of the array element to `char*` is a good start for minimal change. Only other change you need is to use `std::string::data` instead of `std::string::c_str`:

```
parts_arr[i] = parts[i].data();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand the underlying problem with the invalid pointers causing the segmentation fault, but I'm a bit confused by your suggestion on how to avoid the cast.

'parts[i].data()' returns a const pointer, while my 'parts_arr[]' elements are 'char*', as you suggested. While the 'char*' type of the array elements avoids the cast in the 'execvp()' call, the line of code you provided does not compile.

Am I just missing some piece of information you provided to resolve this issue?

Comment: Turns out I was using the C++14 standard to compile my code, which does not feature the non-const overload of `std::string::data`. Switching to C++17 resolved the problem.